# C# How to implement property names like in ValueTuple

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

I am wondering how property naming works in ValueTuples as I want to implement something similar in my own Collection type (Generic OrderedDictionary).

with ValueTuples you can do the following to create named properties (I am aware it compiles to the same IL code)

```
(string TupleName1, bool OtherTuplename2) a = (string.Empty, false);
a.OtherTuplename2 = true;
a.TupleName1 = "test";
```

How would I go about implementing something similar for my own Collection type which currently implements `TKey` and `TValue`
(My end goal being able to use `.OtherNameForKey` instead of `.Key`)

Comment: Tuples have compiler support. There is no straightforward way to do this AFAIK

Comment: create a class for the items instead of relying on tuples?

Comment: I am not relying on tuples, I was wondering how Tuples implemented the naming of properties. Unfortunately it sounds like there is no way for custom classes/types to achieve the same effect

Comment: You can implement deconstruction to deconstruct your class into properties like a tuple would do. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct the user defined type section